# How to remove TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 from an OKD 3.11 cluster?

Tags: okd

I installed an **OKD 3.11** cluster on a set of IaaS servers
Unfortunalety, a security check revealed the following problems:
SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported
TLS Version 1.0 Protocol Detection
TLS Version 1.1 Protocol Detection
I could find out that all culprits are processes that were installed with OKD: haproxy, etcd, and kube-rbac-p
Does anyone happen to know how I can fix these issues - how to disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 and use correct cipher suites?

Answer (score 0):

doc: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#ciphers

check value of ROUTER_CIPHERS
probably null

> oc get dc/router  -n default -o yaml

and set it

> oc set env dc/router ROUTER_CIPHERS=modern -n default

works after router redeploy